# Execute two functions synchronously in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, mean-stack

How to execute two MongoDB functions synchronously? I've tried the below code, but that way looks like callback-hell.

```
Model.updateOne(() => {  --- update a value 
  .then(e => {
    Model.aggregate () ---find a maximum value in the model
  })
```

Comment: I dont' know how to execute Model.aggregate after Model.updateOne() function.The way that I did is like a callback hell

Comment: Could you add more detail about what you're trying to accomplish, and why what you've tried hasn't worked? Also, are you trying to execute those function sequentially or concurrently?